# How to share android application in different smart phone

Tags: android, sharing, mobile-phones, distribute

I have made one smart phone application and now I want to share with some specific people who can use it, without sharing any source code and without making it commercial.

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Just upload Apk to your server and give link to person to whom you want to share ....

And onether way to dirctly run application on their device with eclipse

Another way is mail apk file to whom you want 2 share.

Comment: So far what i did, made one application using android SDK using eclipse and tested in one mobile phone. Now I want to share with some more people so then they can test that.

Answer (score 0):

When you run the application, you can find the apk in bin folder. Just take that apk and email it.